# Which email sent within the day is opened?

Tags: sql, excel

I have the table below, and I am trying to add a column that shows after which email in a given day that the person opens the email, and after which email in a given day they respond.

```
ID      Email_Opened   Email_Replied      Email_Date
12227        1              0             2020-05-05
12227        0              0             2020-05-06
12227        0              0             2020-05-06
12227        1              1             2020-05-06
12227        1              1             2020-07-01
12228        0              0             2020-05-06
12229        1              0             2020-05-06
12229        0              0             2020-05-06
12229        0              0             2020-05-09
```

I want the table to look like below:

```
ID      Email_Opened   Email_Replied      Email_Date   Open_Rank    Reply_Rank
12227        1              0             2020-05-05       1             0
12227        0              0             2020-05-06       0             0
12227        0              0             2020-05-06       0             0
12227        1              1             2020-05-06       3             3
12227        1              1             2020-07-01       1             1
12228        0              0             2020-05-06       0             0
12229        1              0             2020-05-06       2             0
12229        0              0             2020-05-06       0             0     
12229        0              0             2020-05-09       0             0
```

To try to explain a bit further, the email sent to ID 12227 on May 5th was the first email to be sent on the day and was opened, but wasn't replied to. Thus, Open_Rank is 1 and Reply_Rank is 0. Similarly, The third email sent the next day was opened and replied, so the Rank columns are 3 and 3.

Is there a way for me on SQL or Excel to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see that the fourth email was sent opened and replied to, so I'm confused.

Comment: My bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong value for the first row with id 12229. This is the first email sent to that ID on that date, yet you have an open rank of 2. I believe that should be 1.

At any rate, I think it's fairly straightforward in Excel as long as you are defining rank by ID and Date. If the date or id changes, then ranks start over.

(1) Sort your data by ID, then Email_Date.

(2) Add a column called "ID_Date_Rank". Formula below.

(3) Add columns for your Open_Rank and Reply_Rank.

Formulas for row2:

```
    ID_Date_Rank: =IF(AND(D2=D1,A2=A1),E1+1,1)

    Open_Rank: =IF(B2=1,E2,0)

    Reply_Rank: =IF(C2=1,E2,0)
```

Drag the formulas down. That's it.

[image]